# Visual Studio Code: How to disable "The .NET Core SDK cannot be located"

Tags: visual-studio-code

So Microsoft decided to be annoying and instead of having a "disable" button in the message, the button takes me to settings but does not highlight the part where I can disable this message.

What exact setting do I need to change to make this error message go away?

Answer (score 5):

Found it. Search for:

Csharp: Suppress Dotnet Install Warning

Thank you Microsoft for wasting my time by making the text "Csharp" instead of what everyone would search for: "C#".